# user input wont recognize click on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a search box that displays select options depending on user input,  I'm using html autocomplete which supplies user options from a js var when the user starts typing, the problem is the select options only display when i type "item1" (in this case) into the search box and click the autocomplete option, if i only type in for example "it" and click "item1" in the autocomplete options then the select options don't display ???????
https://jsfiddle.net/JohnONeil/Lcs4brxy/105/
pretty sure its something here

```
if ($(this).val() == 'item1')
  $("#userinput").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'item1') {
      $('#userinput1div').show();
      $('#userinput1').attr('required', '');
      $('userinput1').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
    }
    else {
      $('#userinput1div').hide();
      $('#userinput1').removeAttr('required');
      $('#userinput1').removeAttr('data-error');
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'item2') {
      $('#userinput2div').show();
      $('#userinput2').attr('required', '');
      $('userinput2').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
    } else {
      $('#userinput2div').hide();
      $('#userinput2').removeAttr('required');
      $('#userinput2').removeAttr('data-error');

    }
  });
$("#userinput").trigger("change");
```

***DEMO:***

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
      increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
      decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

$("#userinput").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'item1') {
    $('#userinput1div').show();
    $('#userinput1').attr('required', '');
    $('userinput1').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
  } else {
    $('#userinput1div').hide();
    $('#userinput1').removeAttr('required');
    $('#userinput1').removeAttr('data-error');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'item2') {
    $('#userinput2div').show();
    $('#userinput2').attr('required', '');
    $('userinput2').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
  } else {
    $('#userinput2div').hide();
    $('#userinput2').removeAttr('required');
    $('#userinput2').removeAttr('data-error');

  }
});

$("#userinput").trigger("change");
var items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
autocomplete(document.getElementById("userinput"), items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form autocomplete="off" action="">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="choose item">
  </div>
  <div id="userinput1div">
    <select id="userinput1">
      <option hidden>Choose sub item</option>
      <option>item1a</option>
      <option>item1b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="userinput2div">
    <select id="userinput2">
      <option hidden>Choose sub item</option>
      <option>item2a</option>
      <option>item2b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Yes, i still haven't solved the problem due to my poor js skills, novice is being kind. However I'm researching js and shall figure it out, your comments have made me search further on the subject of js which is positive. Thank you

Comment: im currently looking at giving things values

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look.. shows how to make this super simple by using jQuery UI

Comment: Thanks again, i was also looking at jqueryUI as a possible solution they have some nice examples here too, https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Autocomplete-Dropdown-Bootstrap-jQuery/  I just got caught up in the problem and wanted to figure it out.

Comment: ive been messing with this too, using BS Select, it works pretty good although it shows the list whereas with autocomplete you dont see anything until the user starts typing  https://jsfiddle.net/JohnONeil/khsgy0c7/

Comment: updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JohnONeil/32yp687u/

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** Are you opposed to using something like [`jQuery Autocomplete`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) for this? I went ahead and created a demo of what it would look like if you used it.. It makes things *super* simple.. See the snippet below titled ***DEMO WITH jQuery-UI***.

***Original Answer:*** This is happening because of how you are setting the value in your `autocomplete` function.. The handler method reads the value of what was typed before the `autocomplete` function is able to set the value of the input.

I suggest fine tuning your `autocomplete` function, or changing your logic behind how you are setting the value.

***ORIGINAL DEMO***

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          alert("CURRENT VAL: ' " +inp.value + " '\r\n\r\n^^^ Then the clicked value is set, via 'autocomplete' function [specifically the 'b.addEventListener('click',..)' handler is where you set the value]\r\n\r\n--This is only working right now because I wrapped the '$('#userinput').change' handler function in a setTimeout! (which you SHOULD NOT DO to fix this!!!)\r\n\r\n");
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
      increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
      decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

$("#userinput").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    alert("CURRENT VAL: ' " + $(this).val() + " '\r\n\r\n^^^ At this stage, in the $('#userinput').change(..) handler, whatever was typed is the current .val() - this is why it is not working..\r\n\r\n");
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    if ($(this).val() == 'item1') {
      $('#userinput1div').show();
      $('#userinput1').attr('required', '');
      $('userinput1').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
    } else {
      $('#userinput1div').hide();
      $('#userinput1').removeAttr('required');
      $('#userinput1').removeAttr('data-error');
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'item2') {
      $('#userinput2div').show();
      $('#userinput2').attr('required', '');
      $('userinput2').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
    } else {
      $('#userinput2div').hide();
      $('#userinput2').removeAttr('required');
      $('#userinput2').removeAttr('data-error');
    }
  }, 300);
});

$("#userinput").trigger("change");
var items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
autocomplete(document.getElementById("userinput"), items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p style="margin-bottom:0px"><small>Type "it" then click on 'item1'</small></p>
<form autocomplete="off" action="">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="choose item">
  </div>
  <div id="userinput1div">
    <select id="userinput1">
      <option hidden>Choose sub item</option>
      <option>item1a</option>
      <option>item1b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="userinput2div">
    <select id="userinput2">
      <option hidden>Choose sub item</option>
      <option>item2a</option>
      <option>item2b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

***DEMO WITH jQuery-UI***

```js
$("#userinput1div").hide();
$("#userinput2div").hide();

const choices = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

$("#userinput").autocomplete({
  source: choices,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    handleChange(ui.item.value);
  }
});

function handleChange(val) {
  if (val == "item1") {
    $("#userinput1div").show();
    $("#userinput1").attr("required", "");
    $("userinput1").attr("data-error", "This field is required.");
  } else {
    $("#userinput1div").hide();
    $("#userinput1").removeAttr("required");
    $("#userinput1").removeAttr("data-error");
  }
  if (val == "item2") {
    $("#userinput2div").show();
    $("#userinput2").attr("required", "");
    $("userinput2").attr("data-error", "This field is required.");
  } else {
    $("#userinput2div").hide();
    $("#userinput2").removeAttr("required");
    $("#userinput2").removeAttr("data-error");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form autocomplete="off" action="">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="choose item">
  </div>
  <div id="userinput1div">
    <select id="userinput1">
      <option hidden>Choose sub item</option>
      <option>item1a</option>
      <option>item1b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="userinput2div">
    <select id="userinput2">
      <option hidden>Choose sub item</option>
      <option>item2a</option>
      <option>item2b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```